# Is there an easy way to automatically solve for non-given variables?

Tags: python

so let's say you have z = x^2+y, is there an easy way to make python solve for any one of the three non-given variables given the other one? That is, I do not want to specify a function for each i.e.:

```
z = f(x,y) = x^2+y
y = h(x,z) = z-x^2
x = g(x,z) = sqrt(z-y)
```

rather I want the universal relation: z=x^2 + y and then python automatically identifying which one to solve for (without me typing a bunch of else if statements).

Comment: if that existed, it should be some built-in basic functionality that everyone would know about, since that is not the case, you either have to look up some library or make your own function (I very much doubt that python has sth like this built-in (at least not in the way you seemingly want and even then, probably not a built-in))

Comment: @Daniel Lubenstein please see my answer, and accept it if it answers your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from sympy import sympify
from sympy.solvers import solve

expr = sympify('x**2+y-z')
res = expr.subs({'x':2,'y':3})

print(res)  # prints 7 − z
solve(res)  # outputs [7]
```

`solve` algebraically solves equations and systems of equations. See more [here](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html).